# Filter test run to tests with given annotation in Android Instrumentation test

Tags: android, unit-testing, annotations

[According to the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/InstrumentationTestRunner.html)

> Filter test run to tests with given annotation: adb shell am
>   instrument -w -e annotation com.android.foo.MyAnnotation
>   com.android.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
>
> If used with other options, the resulting test run will contain the
>   union of the two options. e.g. "-e size large -e annotation
>   com.android.foo.MyAnnotation" will run only tests with both the
>   LargeTest and "com.android.foo.MyAnnotation" annotations.

I created a annotation class as below:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface DeviceOnly {
}
```

And marked some test cases with @DeviceOnly annotation.

When I run the test suite

```
adb shell am instrument -w -e annotation com.foo.annotation.DeviceOnly com.foo.foo/android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner
```

The complete test suite gets executed without filtering?Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: Have not looked at it any further...Currently have different test suites to run on simulator and one on Device only as a workaround

Comment: I had the same issue when I misspelled the annotation on the command line. Make sure the package name is correct.